# I am now going to the US to work from the office there for a couple of weeks. What about european bank holidays?

Tags: holidays

Essentially a bank holiday will coincide with my trip in the US (I work in Europe). I am wondering if I'd be entitled to get that day back as vacation or something equivalent.

I don't feel comfortable just staying in the hotel, since the company is flying me over to the US to get to meet people in that office and do some face to face work.

How would I handle this?

Comment: Are you going to be in the USA on July 4? If so, I would work with your American colleagues on your bank holiday and take off July 4.

Comment: No, just in June :(

Answer (score 11, accepted):

While on site in the US you should follow US work schedules.  Do not stay at the hotel or not show up to the US office simply because it is a European holiday.

Make sure to speak to your manager and remind him that you will be working in the US during this holiday.  Ask if you are entitled to a compensatory day when you return to Europe.  Most managers are flexible enough to allow for this.

Comment: All of this. If it was me, I would "tell, not ask", treating the missed bank holiday as time in lieu, to be taken later.

Comment: "While on site in the US you should follow US work schedules" - I'm not sure that's an airtight assumption. I've had a few international working relationships where that was true, but others where people from one country were visiting another, yet kept the holiday and hour schedules they would have had at their original office/location (typically because of a union or contract that explicitly defined schedules). In the end, I think your second paragraph is the best advice, just ask your manager.

Answer (score 2):

1. Go to work on that day in the US. Don't skip it.
2. Figure out what your goals/options are. You could ask for a compensation day, once your back, you could ask to get the extra day paid out, or you could ask for some other benefit in return
3. Look at your employee handbook or HR policies, check if something is in there.
4. Talk to your manager about what you want to happen and why. Get her input and feedback and chance are you are going to agree on something, that works for both of you
5. Don't worry whether you are "Entitled" to anything. Your manager can easily give an extra day even if you are not "entitled, and he can easily withhold a day even though you are entitled and there wouldn't be a whole lot you can do about it.

Comment: It may be an easy option. Once I was at a conference in Singapore which, for some strange reason, did not observe the US 4th of July holiday. By company policy, I recorded that day as working, and they converted the holiday time I would have put down to vacation time automatically.

Answer (score 1):

It happened to me, worked outside the country and hadn’t realised everyone else would be working. I called HR back home, and we agreed it would make most sense if I worked that day, and the company gave me an extra day holiday to take back home.